# Using standard error of estimate instead of mean in a t-test?

Tags: regression, t-test, standard-error

I am pretty new in the realm of statistics of testing differences. I do know the basic t-test that tests differences of means (or against that of null effect) in which we use standard error of the mean as the "noise".

A question arises however, for estimates that are not "mean" in the normal sense, like those quantities related to regression, they have a standard error of estimate instead of mean. Is there an inherent difference between the two slightly different named SEs? Can I use the standard error of estimate in a t-test for those quantities that are not "mean"?

Thank you.

Comment: The t test is not intrinsically related to "means." It *is* intrinsically related to value of the ratio of a normal random variable to the square root of a chi-squared random variable, which is itself a sum of squares of normal random variables. If you look closely, you'll see that the difference of means of normally distributed random numbers scaled by standard error meets this requirement. So does the quantity that is the value of the regression coefficients. I suppose you can call that a "Convenient Truth."

Comment: Thanks! This gives a lot of insight into the question. I will think about that for a while.

Comment: @Peter small correction: the denominator in a standard t (as used in a t-test) is not simply $\sqrt{\chi^2}$, but $\sqrt{\chi^2/\nu}$.

Comment: @Glen_b, yes, of course! Thanks. I didn't want to get too technical in a comment-quality answer, but for correctness's sake, I appreciate your amendment and hope the OP understands it well enough for his own sake.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what is actually a random variable. The "random" nature of a mean is given by the random sampling of a population of observation, right? It seems to me that anything that has an uncertainty (e.g. standard error) associated with it can be said as random because it can take on more than one value, is it? Or maybe I ask in another way, what are some example of a fixed variable?